# Renomear aba planilha

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Estou tendo problemas ao renomear o nome de uma aba do arquivo Excell. Eu estou debugando e após ele dar o set com o nome novo..eu consigo ver o nome novo alterado na execução mas na prática o arquivo em si não é alterado. Alguém ?

```
private static void prepararPlanilha() {
        try {
            final int quantidadeAbas = AppUtils.workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            boolean possuiSheet = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= quantidadeAbas; i++) {
                sheet = AppUtils.loadPlanilha(i);
                if (sheet.getSheetName().length() > 2) {
                    AppUtils.workbook.setSheetName(i, sufixo);
                }
                if (sheet.getSheetName().equals(sufixo)) {
                    possuiSheet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!possuiSheet) {
                AppUtils.workbook.createSheet(sufixo);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Planilha inválida");
        }
        AppUtils.closeWorkbook();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está alterando o nome da aba apenas em memória. Você precisa chamar o `workbook.write` para poder escrever no arquivo as suas alterações.

Exemplo:

```
String inputPath = "path";
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputPath);

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
workbook.setSheetName(0, "NewName");

inputStream.close();

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(inputPath);
workbook.write(outputStream);

outputStream.close();
workbook.close();
```

Lembrando que o `InputStream` precisa ser fechado antes de chamar o `write`.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado.